# How to extract text between two words in a document by python3 re?

Tags: python, python-re

I wan to extract text between `Love` and `OK` with following code but it does not work.

```
document = "This is a document with random words Love apples ornages pears OK some thing Love jeep plane car OK any more Love water cola coffee OK bra bra."

x = re.search("^Love.*OK$", document)
```

I want to get follwing text: `apples ornages pears jeep plane car water cola coffee`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using your current regex pattern (modified slightly) eith `re.findall`, to find all substring matches.  Then, join the resulting array together as a single string.

```
document = "This is a document with random words Love apples oranges pears OK some thing Love jeep plane car OK any more Love water cola coffee OK bra bra."
matches = re.findall(r'\bLove (.*?) OK\b', document)
print(' '.join(matches))
```

This prints:

```
apples oranges pears jeep plane car water cola coffee
```

Explanation:

The regex pattern `\bLove (.*?) OK\b` will capture the content between each `Love ... OK` set of markers.  This generates, in this case, three substrings.  We then join the output array from `re.findall` into a single string using `join()`.

Comment: Could you explain more about this answer. I am a beginner. @Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

Get a list of all matching patterns using `re.findall()`.

> `Love\s(.*?)\sOK` - This pattern matches anything that is present in between the word `Love` and `OK`.

```
import re
s = "this is a document with random words Love apples ornages pears OK Love jeep plane car OK Love water cola coffee OK bra bra."
d = re.findall('Love\s(.*?)\sOK', s)

print(d)
print(' '.join(d))
```

```
['apples ornages pears', 'jeep plane car', 'water cola coffee']

apples ornages pears jeep plane car water cola coffee
```

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `^` is for beginning of string, and `$` for end of string, so that doesn't apply here.

---

Just remove them and it'll work, use `.*?` for matching the smallest string

```
import re

document = "This is a document with random words Love apples ornages pears OK some thing Love jeep plane car OK any more Love water cola coffee OK bra bra."

x = re.search("Love.*?OK", document).group()
print(x)  # Love apples ornages pears OK

x = re.search("Love.*OK", document).group()
print(x)  # Love apples ornages pears OK some thing Love jeep plane car OK any more Love water cola coffee OK
```